# Flask Blueprint 404

Tags: python, flask

I get a 404 when trying to access a route defined in a Flask Blueprint and I do not see why. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong (I'm new to Flask and Python in general so it could be something basic)?

My blueprint (`test.py`):

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy

test_blueprint = Blueprint(
    'test_blueprint', __name__, url_prefix='/test')


@test_blueprint.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_tests():

    return jsonify([{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Foo"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Bar"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Baz"
    }]), 200
```

My `app.py`:

```
from test import test_blueprint

from flask import abort, Flask
from os import environ


def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object('config.settings')
    app.template_folder = app.config.get('TEMPLATE_FOLDER', 'templates')
    app.url_map.strict_slashes = False

    app.register_blueprint(test_blueprint)

    return app
```

The result of hitting `http://127.0.0.1:5000/test` is:

```
(venv) mymachine:api myusername$ python run.py
 * Restarting with stat
Starting server at 127.0.0.1 listening on port 5000 in DEBUG mode
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 123-456-789
127.0.0.1 - - [2018-06-03 17:02:56] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 342 0.012197
```

`app.py` and `test.py` are in the same directory, fyi.

---

Extra Info:
Since you can see above that I am starting this with a file named `run.py` here is that file, for completeness:

```
from flask_failsafe import failsafe
from gevent import monkey
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
from werkzeug.serving import run_with_reloader

@failsafe
def failsafe_app():
    from app import create_app
    return create_app()


app = failsafe_app()


@run_with_reloader
def run():

    app.debug = app.config['DEBUG']

    print('Starting server at %s listening on port %s %s' %
          (app.config['HOST'], app.config['PORT'], 'in DEBUG mode'
           if app.config['DEBUG'] else ''))

    if app.config['DEBUG']:
        http_server = WSGIServer((app.config['HOST'], app.config['PORT']),
                                 DebuggedApplication(app))
    else:
        if app.config['REQUEST_LOGGING']:
            http_server = WSGIServer((app.config['HOST'], app.config['PORT']),
                                     app)
        else:
            http_server = WSGIServer(
                (app.config['HOST'], app.config['PORT']), app, log=None)

    http_server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: you defined a `url_prefix='/test'`, so the url should be `http://127.0.0.1:5000/test/test`

Comment: Dang it, I knew it would be stupid simple. Thank you. If you answer this I can accept your fix. @PRMoureu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you define the blueprint with an `url_prefix`, every rules of this blueprint will concatenate this prefix with the given routes

In your example, the url should be `http://127.0.0.1:5000/test/test` to access the view `get_all_tests`.

Answer (score -1):

Your port number is in the wrong place in the url.

It should be `http://127.0.0.1:5000/test`

As you had it, you're hitting the standard port 80, looking for the url `/test:5000`.

Comment: Ugh... that was just a typo from when I entered the question, sorry. I have corrected it to what I am actually using